# Coding for an ordered covariate

Tags: categorical-data, predictor

I am performing ordinal regression, I have 5 response categories and several predictors both continuous and categorical. I would like to add a predictor which is categorical but ordered (1, 2, 3, 4). I don't think it would be appropriate to apply the usual dummy coding for unordered categorical predictors, but when I searched for how to code this I did not find much information. 
In [Steyerberg (2009)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+&+health/book/978-0-387-77243-1) "linear coding" or "assuming linearity of the predictor effect" is mentioned, but without further details. 
Does it mean I just use my ordered values as they are, i.e. use them as a continuous variable?

Comment: I think that is what is meant. I haven't seen a great solution to ordered categorical variables. It seems like it is either dummy coding, assume linearity, or use some overly complex non-linear function.

Comment: @Charles You could choose any simple nonlinear function you liked. You could also assign any numeric scores that make substantive sense, or use a variety of more systematic methods to assign scores based on the relative frequencies of the ordinal variable.

Comment: @Nick: What are those systematic methods?

Comment: Scores calculated from the data somehow, e.g. normal or logistic scores, scores from correspondence analysis. I mean any method not based on intuition, guesswork or convention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check out [Gertheiss & Tutz, Penalized Regression with Ordinal Predictors](http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/2100/1/tr015.pdf), & their R package [ordPens](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordPens).
They say:–

> Rather than estimating the parameters by simple maximum likelihood methods we propose to penalize differences between coefficients of adjacent categories
>   in the estimation procedure. The rationale behind is as follows: the response $y$ is assumed to change slowly between two adjacent categories of the independent variable. In other words, we try to avoid high jumps and prefer a smoother coefficient vector.

Comment: More active discussion is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/continuous-dependent-variable-with-ordinal-independent-variable).