# How must one handle ordinal independent variables when modeling interactions?

Tags: regression, interaction, ordinal-data, binary-data, predictor

Suppose I have two independent variables, `X1` and `X2`. `X1` is binary--coded as 1 or 0. `X2` has three ordered but most likely not equidistant levels--let's call them "low," "medium," and "high." I want to know if there is a *significant interaction* between X1 and X2 in a regression I am running.

Classically, one would treat `X2` as an ordinal variable. However, the interaction between `X1` and `X2` is not fully crossed--there are no observations for which `X1` is equal to 0 and `X2` is equal to "medium." This makes the coefficients matrix rank-deficient--one factor level combination is "missing." Moreover, when you include an ordinal variable as an independent variable in a model in R, it models these variables using linear and quadratic terms (which is logical), which introduces a level of complexity into my model I'm not comfortable with, if I can avoid it.

I see two alternative approaches:

1. Removal all observations for which `X2` is equal to "medium" so that I no longer have to treat `X2` as anything other than a binary factor. In that case, the interaction between `X1` and `X2` would become fully crossed. This throws away data though, so I'd rather not go this route.
2. Violate the "statistics rules" I had been taught and treat `X2` as continuous/numeric instead, coded as something like 0, 1, and 2 for "low," "medium," and "high," respectively. The model would run this way, but the coefficients would be a little messy to interpret, and so this would only be a qualitative assessment of significance (which would probably be good enough, actually, as long as it was unbiased).

I would opt for option 2, but I was wondering if this is the "right" way to proceed and, if not, what alternatives am I maybe not considering?

P.S. I have seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93680/treating-ordinal-variables-as-continuous-for-regression-problems) that some fields treat ordinal variables as continuous routinely. However, as discussed in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-treat-categorical-data-as-continuous), one must think carefully about what one is really after when considering this type of question. For me, I am guessing that there is either going to be a very significant interaction, or a very insignificant one. As such, a "messy" but "unbiased" approach would be sufficient, I think?

Edit: For a test model, I ran both approaches listed above and the beta coefficients and P values for the interaction term end up being very, very similar between the two models. My conclusion would be the same in each case (the interaction is significant at alpha = 0.05). Does this potentially strengthen my justification for choosing option 2?