# Multiple regression for categorical variable which have more than 3 levels

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have 3 categorical independent variable and all the variables are more than 2 categories like 6 locations, 4 types, 6 maturity levels. Can I still use multiple regression? If so, how can I do that? If not, is there a better test for my experiment?

I was asked to clarify more:
To explain more: I have 6 dependent variables and I want to see, for example if the location has an effect on my dependent variables. should I look at this effect one-by-one? Can I look the effect of 3 categorical independent variable on a dependent variable at the same time?

Comment: Re the edit: did you perhaps write "dependent" for "independent"?

Comment: I have 3 categorical independent variable and 6 independent variable as I wrote in the original question.

Comment: Again your comment is confusing.  You wrote "6 dependent" in the question but now your comment says "6 independent"!

Comment: Sorry @whuber that was a typo! As stated in the original question, I have 3 categorical independent variable and 6 dependent variables and I am trying to explain the effect of these 3 categorical variables on each of those 6 independent variables.

Comment: I give up...once again you refer to those 6 variables both as "dependent" and "independent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use dummy variables (be sure to leave out one for your reference category), but the "maturity levels" sounds ordinal. [Here's a related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/continuous-dependent-variable-with-ordinal-independent-variable/87418#87418) with some interesting discussion about how to handle an ordinal predictor.

Comment: I am completely new so I am trying to learn. So let's say I am using dummy variables. Should the number of observations in the categories be same? I have read it somewhere but I might get confused since I am trying to learn it in a short time period.

Comment: There is no requirement for categories to be equally numerous. Nevertheless you're at the mercy of those small frequencies. The coefficient estimate inevitably is more sensitive to individual values. This can help or hinder.

Answer (score 1):

You can include dummy variables for each categorical variable or you can refer to multi-factor ANOVA tests (see e.g., this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-lm-function-with-categorical-predictors/))

Comment: The same method in different guises!