# Logistic regression and different Independent variable classes - what to do?

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm trying to run a logistic regression in R to determine what independent variables may determine if a sea turtle becomes entangled in fishing net or not.  My independent variables vary significantly from each other in both scale and class e.g. Mesh size (7mm-1500mm), Twine diameter(0.33-4mm) Colour (red,blue green etc.)  Construction (Multi or Mono).  Must I first convert all independent variables to a similar scale to run a glm command.  If so how do I standardise factors such as Colour and Construction?  Also is it necessary to produce a testing dataset and a training data set as I see some people do this and others incorporate the entire model in the `glm` command ?

Comment: Your main question is largely a duplicate of [Can I use multiple regression when I have mixed categorical and continuous predictors?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6353/22228) (although you are performing logistic regression, the answer is the same).

Comment: The answer is probably no and no. But read [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29782/67822) and [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124477/67822). Note Prof. Harrell' [comment at the bottom of the question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48360/67822). My understanding is that separating testing and training is done in the context of machine learning - you want to see your out of sample error with the idea not of identifying relationships between iv and dv, but rather to make predictions on future data.